# Makefile relink error

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to get this makefile relink and not recompile unessecarily files that aren't modified. The "libft" is my library and doesnt have any errors. The error that I am having when doing

```
make
```

is :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `main.o', needed by `ft_printf'.  Stop.
```

My makefile is:

```
NAME = ft_printf

SRC = main.c\
  ft_printf.c\
  parser_main.c\
  utils.c\
  debug_funcs.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

SRC_PATH = srcs/

SRC_POS = $(addprefix $(SRC_PATH),$(SRC))

INC = -I includes

LIBFT = libft/libft.a

CC = gcc

FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(NAME) $(LIBFT)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(FLAGS)
$(LIBFT):
    make -C ./libft/

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)
    make clean -C ./libft/

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)
    make fclean -C ./libft/

re: fclean all
```

Any idea ? I can't figure it out and i think it's because %.o:%.c isn't called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the existence of these variables:

```
SRC_PATH = srcs/    
SRC_POS = $(addprefix $(SRC_PATH),$(SRC))
```

I'm guessing that your source files actually live in `srcs/` whereas you're building your object files in `.` So this pattern rule:

```
%.o: %.c
```

when trying to match `main.o` won't find a `main.c` since that file really is `srcs/main.c`. Since that pattern doesn't match, the rule itself isn't considered, and since no other rule is found, you get an error.

Instead, try:

```
%.o : $(SRC_PATH)/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(FLAGS)
```

Comment: @Seluj78 You're welcome and welcome to SO! See [what to do when somebody answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)