# What does it mean for a Makefile to "relink"?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, compilation, gnu-make

Can someone explain in simple terms:

1. What does it mean for a Makefile to **relink** ?
2. Why does it happen?
3. How to avoid it?

---

Comment: I've never heard this term before.  Could you please tell us where you saw it?

Comment: My assignment says... I lose points if my makefile "**relinks**".. no clue either.

Comment: I would just ask your professor to clarify what they mean. If you're getting some kind of linking error post your makefile in the question.

Comment: I guess "relink" means that the binary is always relinking when running `make` multiple times. One example of this issue is in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/42718392/72178.

Comment: Other ppl have the same issue like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722100/makefile-relink-error?rq=1), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718392/how-to-avoid-my-makefile-to-relink), but the answers are specific.. I'm hoping someone could explain it in a general sense.

Comment: [Auto dependency generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)

Answer (score 5):

A primary feature of `make` is that dependencies are specified in a `makefile` (often named `makefile` but may have other names such as `MyRules.mk`) in a form like:

```
FileX: FileA FileB FileC
    Command to make FileX from FileA FileB FileC
```

Given this dependency, if any of `FileA`, `FileB`, or `FileC` has a modification time later than the modification time of `FileX`, then `make` will execute the command to make a new version of `FileX`.

A common dependency rule says that an object file depends on a C source file and some header files, such as:

```
foo.o: foo.c foo.h project.h
    $(CC) -c foo.c
```

In makefiles for substantial projects, the rules and lists of files are often more complicated, using multiple symbols to convey commands, options, and lists of files.

Another common rule says to make an executable file out of object files:

```
MyProgram: foo.o bar.o baz.o
    $(LD) -o $@ $^
```

In this context, “relink” merely means that make will execute the command to link objects into an executable again. It happens either because one of the prerequisite files (an object file, often with a name ending in `.o`) is newer than the target executable file or because the rules in the makefile have not been written to properly express the dependencies.

Avoiding it is a matter of understanding how `make` and its rules and makefiles work.